# Can we track an image uploaded in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, image, tracking

This is the case, if we can track the images that we upload to the facebook page in order to known who download the images and located maybe the IP or the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a custom Facebook application that grabs user information based on the Facebook open graph for this. Users will have to allow your application to access their data first though. there is no way to track user information simply by uploading a photo on your wall/photo albums

Comment: And even then, once a user takes the photo and uploads it again themselves somewhere on Facebook again, there will be no more “tracking” …